# Can I convert this loop to a map(lambda x: .. )) somehow?

Tags: python, optimization, lambda

I'm trying to optimize a method that counts the number of `1`s in the binary representation of each number from `0 -> num`

```
# Example of how the below works, for clarity
#
# base => [0,1,1,2,1,2,2]
# index => 7
#
#   {7} --
#       bin(7)              :   111
#       bin(7-1)            :   110
#       111 & 110           :   110 (6)
#       append(base[6]+1)   :   append(3)
#     //end 7
#
# base => [0,1,1,2,1,2,2,3]

def countBits(num):
    index = 1
    base = [0]

    while(index <= num):
        base.append(base[(index & (index - 1))]+1)
        index += 1

    return base
```

I was wondering if there's a way I can convert the while loop into something that could be done in place rather than looped? My first idea was to do something like...

`base.append(map(lambda index: base[(index & (index -1))]+1, num))`

But this doesn't really do anything at all.. `base` remains unchanged. I assume I just don't fully understand what the `map(lambda x:...)` syntax does. I've only used it a couple times, for straightforward calls on lists.

Comment: do this actually work?

Comment: Yep! Just updated with a comment explaining one example

Comment: It's quite difficult to turn a loop into a list comprehension or `map` expression, if the body of the loop makes reference to the thing you're appending to. `base.append(base[...])` is the red flag that you won't have an easy time translating into a one-liner.

Comment: @MrDuk you could solve this with `map`, however you won't be able to involve `lambda` because map won't modify `base` until it's completely exhausted whatever it iterates over.

Comment: `map(lambda n:bin(n).count('1'), range(num+1))`

Comment: Oh, `lambda` isn't a requirement if solely using `map` can work... I was just guessing at what to try first honestly.

Comment: @Daniel -- that's cool, but I want to go off the solution I already have if possible, not change it completely. Thanks though

Comment: @MrDuk I'm realizing the solution I was thinking of wasn't particularly useful, and wouldn't increase efficiency (more likely it would make it worse).

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 (functional style) solutions, but they are hardly "in place". And, probably, both will work slower then loop.

First not with map but with reduce:

```
def countBits2(num):
    from functools import reduce
    index = 1;
    base = reduce( lambda base, index: (base.append( base[(index & (index - 1))]+1 ), base)[1], range( 1, num+1 ), [0] )
    return base
```

Second with map:

```
def countBits3( num ):
    base = [0]     
    def m_append( index ):
        val = base[(index & (index - 1))]+1
        base.append( val )
        return val

    return [0] + list( map( m_append, range( 1, num+1) ) )
    #also possible to return base
    #list( map( ... ) ) # list required to force mapping on py3
    #return base
```

`m_append` may be rewritten to lambda (same way as in reduce attempt) but it will be very long lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something like this?

```
num = 11

base = [0]
for _ in range(1, num):
    base.extend(map(lambda index: base[(index & (index -1))] + 1, [_]))
```

Result:

```
[0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2]
```